# PostgreSQL - assign exact date based on day of month

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, join

I don't even know where to start with this one, or if it's even possible to do in PostgreSQL (or if I'll just need to handle it in my code)

I have a table of Bills, which specify which day of the month each one is due

| id | bill_name | day_of_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mortgage | 5 |
| 2 | Car Payment | 11 |
| 3 | Water | 14 |
| 4 | Electricity | 27 |

and I have a table of 4 week Periods

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07 Sep 2022 | 04 Oct 2022 |
| 2 | 05 Sep 2022 | 01 Nov 2022 |
| 3 | 02 Nov 2022 | 29 Dec 2022 |

I want to join the two tables together and determine if each bill falls within the start and end of a period and then assign its exact date

I want to end up with an *exact_date* column

| start | end | bill_name | day_of_month | exact_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07 Sep 2022 | 04 Oct 2022 | Car Payment | 11 | 11 Sep 2022 |
| 07 Sep 2022 | 04 Oct 2022 | Water | 14 | 14 Sept 2022 |
| 07 Sep 2022 | 04 Oct 2022 | Electricity | 27 | 27 Sep 2022 |
| 05 Oct 2022 | 01 Nov 2022 | Mortgage | 5 | 5 Oct 2022 |
| 05 Oct 2022 | 01 Nov 2022 | Car Payment | 11 | 11 Oct 2022 |
| 05 Oct 2022 | 01 Nov 2022 | Water | 14 | 14 Oct 2022 |
| 05 Oct 2022 | 01 Nov 2022 | Electricity | 27 | 27 Oct 2022 |
| 02 Nov 2022 | 29 Dec 2022 | Mortgage | 5 | 5 Nov 2022 |
| 02 Nov 2022 | 29 Dec 2022 | Car Payment | 11 | 11 Nov 2022 |
| 02 Nov 2022 | 29 Dec 2022 | Water | 14 | 14 Nov 2022 |
| 02 Nov 2022 | 29 Dec 2022 | Electricity | 27 | 27 Nov 2022 |

Is this possible? Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: cross join both tables, seek the first da of the month and add the days. Generate uin anCTe a series of 1-3 so that you get all three momth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select p.start, p.end, b.bill_name, b.day_of_month, 
       gs.exact_date::date
  from periods p
       cross join lateral generate_series(
                            p.start, p.end, interval '1 day') as gs(exact_date)
       join bills b on b.day_of_month = extract(day from gs.exact_date)
 order by exact_date;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rHf9EOsq)

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join the tables and add the exact date(-1)

```
SELECT "start", "end","bill_name", "day_of_month" ,date_trunc('month', "start")::date + "day_of_month" - 1
FROM periods CROSS JOIN due
```

```
| start               | end                  | bill\_name | day\_of\_month | ?column? |
|:--------------------|:---------------------|:-----------|---------------:|:---------|
| 2022-09-07 02:00:00 | 2022-10-04 02:00:00  | Mortgage    | 5             | 2022-09-05 |
| 2022-09-07 02:00:00 | 2022-10-04 02:00:00  | Car Payment | 11            | 2022-09-11 |
| 2022-09-07 02:00:00 | 2022-10-04 02:00:00  | Water       | 14            | 2022-09-14 |
| 2022-09-07 02:00:00 | 2022-10-04 02:00:00  | Electricity | 27            | 2022-09-27 |
| 2022-10-05 02:00:00 | 2022-11-01 01:00:00  | Mortgage    | 5             | 2022-10-05 |
| 2022-10-05 02:00:00 | 2022-11-01 01:00:00  | Car Payment | 11            | 2022-10-11 |
| 2022-10-05 02:00:00 | 2022-11-01 01:00:00  | Water       | 14            | 2022-10-14 |
| 2022-10-05 02:00:00 | 2022-11-01 01:00:00  | Electricity | 27            | 2022-10-27 |
| 2022-11-02 01:00:00 | 2022-12-29 01:00:00  | Mortgage    | 5             | 2022-11-05 |
| 2022-11-02 01:00:00 | 2022-12-29 01:00:00  | Car Payment | 11            | 2022-11-11 |
| 2022-11-02 01:00:00 | 2022-12-29 01:00:00  | Water       | 14            | 2022-11-14 |
| 2022-11-02 01:00:00 | 2022-12-29 01:00:00  | Electricity | 27            | 2022-11-27 |
```

> ```
> SELECT 12
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/21mqbOH1)